# Working with Excel Worksheet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-office

I have a Excel version problem with an Windows Forms Tool.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[3];
ws.Delete();
 ws = myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[3];
```

This works perfectly with Excel 2010 but throws the following Exception in

> Excel 2013: "0x8002000B DISP_E_BADINDEX"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851642/c-sharp-excel-interop-exception-from-hresult-disp-e-badindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel only creates one Worksheet in a new document by default, unlike 3 Worksheets for Excel 2010.

So BADINDEX means you don't have an Index of 3