# How to pass dateTimePicker Value to Crystal Report in c#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am want to pass datetimepicker Value to Crystal report to show rows Between those date
i am using this code

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
        DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString());
        RPT.rpt_all_bocket_transaction myReport = new RPT.rpt_all_bocket_transaction();
        myReport.SetParameterValue("@D1",d1);
        myReport.SetParameterValue("@D2",d2);
        RPT.frm_rpt myForm = new RPT.frm_rpt();
        myForm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
        myForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

my stored Proceduer work fine without crystal report
but when i trying to search between two date i get this error

```
Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
```

Comment: Invalid index implies that maybe there is no parameter defined with a key of "@D1" or "@D2"...

Comment: my parameters in stored procedure are :
"@D1 datetime , @D2 datetime"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Excel interop: Exception from HRESULT (DISP\_E\_BADINDEX)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851642/c-sharp-excel-interop-exception-from-hresult-disp-e-badindex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and works. Make sure you are calling the correct report in  your code.

```
RPT.rpt_all_bocket_transaction
```

Make sure to check your report is connected with the correct procedure.
I don't see any other mistakes in your code.

Comment: my stored procedure was right , but i was call another report with non parameter , thank you